# Add a new lag column, after ordering?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C54we.png)I am trying to produce a lag column after ordering, and am not sure how to do it

```
SELECT 
     Date
      ,Vehicle
      ,OdoReadingMiles   
  FROM [Fleet].[DwhTriscanChargeouts]
  order by convert(datetime, date, 103), Vehicle ASC
  LAG (OdoReadingMiles,1) Over (ORDER BY Vehicle) AS New
```

I want to be able to sort the dataset by date order, before using the Lag function. I have tried to put the Lag function before, but that doesnt seem to work?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: . . . That might be because of `,` missing between orders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `partition by`:

```
SELECT Date, Vehicle, OdoReadingMiles,
       LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY date) AS prev_OdoReadingMiles
FROM [Fleet].[DwhTriscanChargeouts];
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I was clear enough in my first post. What I want is the dataset to be ordered by both date and vehicle number, and then the lag function to be used. I have tried variations of your above code but no luck

Comment: @AmmarWahid . . . Try adding an `order by` to the outer query if you want a particular order.  It makes no sense, actually, to look at the odometer reading on different vehicles, so this query does something useful.